# Erase element of struct vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete a `Team Roster` element from the `playerRoster` vector given a user defined jersey number.  The problem I am running into is the `.erase` function isn't working.

```
struct TeamRoster {
   int jerseyNumber;
   int playerRating;
};

int numPlayers = 5;
int searchValue = 0;
vector<TeamRoster> playerRoster(numPlayers);
TeamRoster newPlayer;

unsigned int i = 0;

cout << "Enter a jersey number: ";
cin >> searchValue;
cout << endl;
for (i = 0; i < playerRoster.size(); ++i) {
   if (playerRoster.at(i).jerseyNumber == searchValue) {
      playerRoster.erase(i);
   }
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:68:36: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<main()::TeamRoster>::erase(unsigned int&)'
            playerRoster.erase(i);
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:64:0,
             from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:1147:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator) [with _Tp = main()::TeamRoster; _Alloc = std::allocator<main()::TeamRoster>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<main()::TeamRoster*, std::vector<main()::TeamRoster> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = main()::TeamRoster*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const main()::TeamRoster*, std::vector<main()::TeamRoster> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const main()::TeamRoster*]
   erase(const_iterator __position)
   ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:1147:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'std::vector<main()::TeamRoster>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const main()::TeamRoster*, std::vector<main()::TeamRoster> >}'
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:1174:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator) [with _Tp = main()::TeamRoster; _Alloc = std::allocator<main()::TeamRoster>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<main()::TeamRoster*, std::vector<main()::TeamRoster> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = main()::TeamRoster*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const main()::TeamRoster*, std::vector<main()::TeamRoster> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const     main()::TeamRoster*]
   erase(const_iterator __first, const_iterator __last)
   ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:1174:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I looked on cplusplus.com and noticed a difference between c++94 and c++11 `iterator erase (const_iterator position);` (11), `iterator erase (iterator position);` (94).  From the error I'm getting, it looks like my compiler is using c++11.

Does `const_iterator` mean that I have to use a constant with the `.erase()` function, and if so, is there a different function that will work in this case?

If this isn't the problem, can you help me figure out what is?

Comment: `erase()` takes an *iterator*, not an `unsigned int`.

Comment: I'm still learning c++, should I go learn what an iterator is and how to use it, or would it be better to figure out a different way to remove an element from a struct vector?

Comment: Iterators are used a lot in modern C++, so it'd be best to read up on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one element you want to erase, you could try code below:

```
for(auto iter = playerRoster.begin(); iter != playerRoster.end(); ++iter){
    if(iter->jerseyNumber == searchValue){
        iter = playerRoster.erase(iter);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to erase all element that match, you could try :

```
for(auto iter = playerRoster.begin(); iter != playerRoster.end(); ){
    if(iter->jerseyNumber == searchValue){
        iter = playerRoster.erase(iter);
    }else{
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

Remember erase return the element after the one that be erased.

Sample code can be found : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: In the sample code they have `.erase(myvector.begin()+5)` . Would `.erase(playerRoster.bigin() + i)` work?

Comment: @JacobBischoff Oh , yes it work, I think. Usually I donot write code that way.

Comment: Erasing all element didn't work for me. I got stuck in the for loop. Solved by replacing '`break;` with `--iter;`.